# Funciones de reemplazo en R. ¿Cuál es su lógica?

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

Una función de reemplazo en R es aquella que tiene el nombre especial `'xxx<-'`

Un ejemplo básico es el que maneja Hadley Wickham en su texto Advanced R:

```
`second<-` <- function(x, value) {
  x[2] <- value
  x
}
x <- 1:10
second(x) <- 5L
x
```

La lista de funciones de reemplazo en las librerías base puede ser obtenida mediante el siguiente código:

```
objs = mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
funs = Filter(is.function, objs)

replacement.funs = funs[grep("[a-zA-Z]+<-$", names(funs))]
str(replacement.funs)
```

Quise explorar un poco usando `is.na` y obtuve un resultado que no entiendo. Intento cambiar las posiciones 1 y 5 del vector x:

```
x <- c(1:3,2:5,1:10)
x
is.na(x) = x[c(1,5)]
x

[1] NA  2 NA  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

¿A qué se debe que los índices modificados sean el 1 y el 3 y no el 1 y 5 como se desea?
Cualquier orientación la agradeceré mucho ya que no he encontrado mucha información al respecto (Imagino que se debe a que las funciones de reemplazo son poco usadas en lo general)

Comment: Alejandro, tienes un pequeño error tipográfico se puede decir, cuando haces `x[c(1,5)]` no estás haciendo `(1,5)` sino `(1,3)` por que `x` es `[(1)  2  (3)  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]`. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¿Te refieres a que el primer vector sólo tiene 3 índices y por eso al indicar x[c(1,5)] me regresa NA para el 1 y el 3 en lugar de 1 y 5?

Comment: No, lo que digo es que `x[c(1,5)]` te va a retornar `c(1,3)`, por que `x=[(1) 2 3 2 (3) 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` te marque mal el indice en mi anterior comentario. Lo que esperas en realidad sería `is.na(x) = c(1,5)`. Si no queda claro te hago una respuesta.